# polygonize and raster tools

Tags: qgis, raster, tools, polygonize

ok simplest question i have asked i think. but im a running QGIS 1.7.4 and there are no other tools in the dropdown menu other than raster calculator. I have seen in a lot of online demos tools below the raster tab.....the one i am interested now in is polygonize...i have searched in the pluggins and no luck......what am i missing

[image: what i see]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using QGIS 1.7.4 Wroclaw and it seemed to be missing some of the element that i was talking about.

Upgraded to QGIS 1.8.0 Lisboa. All present and correct.

QGIS is by far the best system out there.

Comment: You would need to enable the GdalTools plugin. It's is installed by default, so it's under 'Manage Plugins' menu.